# comparison of strings with a another string characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

assume I have two strings a="a-b-c" and another one is b="a-b".
I want to check if string a contains every alphabet of string b.

Comment: Could you post what code you have?

Comment: With "every alphabet" you mean "every character"? Do the characters have to occur in the same order?

Comment: Just iterate over b characters and test if they're present in a (using indexOf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that there are several ways and orders you could potentially get both Strings represented; that said, the most straight forward way would be to check for each char in String b if it is indeed contained in String a. For that purpose, you could easily call `indexOf(currentCharFromStringB)` on String a.

I hope the following example helps you to see my idea:

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blue") != -1; // true
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Bloe") != -1; // false
```

Some pseudo code would be:

```
for each char in b
     for each char in a
        is a in b?
```

Now, it's up to you, dealing how you want to extract or represent each character of String B.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution will be to **read the two strings into two [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)** of characters. After doing so, "every character in b in in a" if and only if `b` is a [*subset*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of `a`. It can be optimized to use only one set (for b) - see pseudo code.

The complexity of this approach is `O(|a|+|b|)` on average using hash table, or `O(log(min{|a|,|b|})*(|a|+|b|))` worst case using tree based. It is much better comparing to a naive solution which will get you `O(|a|*|b|)` if you search each and every character.

**Pseudo code:**

```
setB <- empty set
for each element e in b:
  setB.add(e)
for each element e in a:
  setB.remove(e) //assuming doing nothing if doesn't exist
return setB.isEmpty()
```

The idea of the optimization is to load the elements (chars) of `b` into a set, and then iterate `a` while removing elements from the set if encountered.

Once you are done iterating `a`, if (and only if) there is a character in `b` that is not in `a` - it will remain in the set and the algorithm will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(a,b) {
    var alphabet = b.split("-");    
    for (var i=0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
      if (a.indexOf(alphabet[i]) == -1)
          return false;
    }   
    return true;
}

func("a-b-c", "a-b");
```

Comment: Note that it is a very inefficient solution (comparing to the alternatives), and runs in `O(|a|*|b|)`.

Comment: @amit Greater O complexity doesn't mean it's slower, especially for short strings as in the question. Building the sets comes with a cost too.

Comment: @dystroy: No, for short strings not, but I'd bet that for any n>10 it will.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
var b = "a-b";
var a = "a-b-c";
var firstArray = b.split("-");
var secArray = a.split("-");
var length = firstArray.lenght;
for(var i =0; i<length; i++)
{
  if(secArray.indexOf(firstArray[i]) != -1)
    continue; //or do something
  else
    break; // or return false.
}
```